# Explanation of White Noise

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have been trying to understand what a White Noise is and also a White noise Process and I have been trying to piece together different definitions that I have found online. I was wondering if my understanding of White Noise is correct

> [These notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e9f2/8ca5f7eb1ea69ee469ab2ac01807923d071e.pdf) say that the the mathematical definition of White Noise is and $0$ mean Generalized Gaussian Processes on $S$ (I believe that $S$ needs to be a smooth function of rapid decrease?), namely $Y(\phi)$, such that the variance of $Y(\phi)$ is $\int_{\mathbb R} \phi(t)^2 dt$.

So from my understanding, let $ \phi(t) \in S $  be a test function then we can consider the generalized stochastic process $$ X(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t)dB_t $$  where $B_t$ is a brownian motion on $\mathbb R$. So $X$ here is the Wiener Integral. It is a standard result that $X(\phi)$ is a $0$-mean Gaussian random variable with variance $\int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t)^2dt $. So according to the above definition, $X$ is a white noise. But, in the same notes linked above, it says that White Noise can be thought of as the derivative of a Brownian Motion, which i'll refer to as $\dot{B}_t$.

Now using the stochastic integration by parts formula we see that $$ -\int_{\mathbb R}\phi '(t)B_tdt = \int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t)dB_t \tag{1} $$ 
and now we will informally denote this last integral as $$ \int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t)\dot{B}_tdt \tag{2} $$
So putting (1) and (2) together we see that $$ -\int_{\mathbb R}\phi '(t)B_tdt = \int_{\mathbb R}\phi(t)\dot{B}_tdt \tag{3} $$
And we now see that $\dot{B}_t$ is the weak or distributional dervitive of the Brownian motion $B_t$.

So now in the same notes listed above, the author says that the process $X(\phi)$, which was already said to be a White Noise, defines a White Noise $\dot{B}$. My question now is that does White Noise refer to both $X$ and $\dot{B}$? If we regard White Noise as the derivative (in the sense of distributions) of a Brownian Motion then $\dot{B}$ is a White Noise. But just using the mathematical definition of a White Noise we also see that $X$ is a White Noise.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: The classical derivative of $B$ does not exist. So certain generalized meaning is needed: one can look at  $\dot B$ paired with a test function. And this is precisely what $X$ stands for.

Comment: So $\dot{B}$ is the weak derivative of $B$ so in other words for any test function $\phi$ we have (3) above holds? I couldn't find a reference online that shows why this weak derivative, $\dot B$, exists? Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: It's a matter of how you refer to this "weak derivative". Say, you can write it as $\int \phi(t) dB_t$ and call a stochastic integral or Wiener integral or whatever. This you can find in any textbook on stochastic integration or stochastic differential equations or just stochastic processes (like our with Mishura).